# Auto Increment Values in Oracle Column

Tags: database, oracle

I have a table in my oracle DB which has a column with random values. Screenshot is attached below :
[image]

I had manually updated the first row to "V0001". Is there any way I can update the rest of the rows to "V0002", "V0003" and so on without manual intervention.

Comment: You could use numbers in the column and add the `V` when selecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a *sequence* for this.  Create a sequence, convert the sequence's .NEXTVAL to a string, use CONCAT() and UPDATE eg:

Table

```
create table demo
as
select dbms_random.string( 'x', 11 ) as vehicleid
from dual
connect by level <= 100 ;

select * from demo fetch first 10 rows only ;
-- output
VEHICLEID
LS23XFRNH5N
47DUDNOIRO9
POS5GQSQLMO
BBEEZJMQZI4
2Q8QE30HM2E
S7M5V40YNTD
N2X1YN0OIE3
...
```

Sequence

```
create sequence vehicleid_seq start with 1 increment by 1 ;
```

Update

```
update demo
set vehicleid = concat( 'V', to_char( vehicleid_seq.nextval, 'FM00000' ) ) ;
```

Result

```
select * from demo order by vehicleid fetch first 10 rows only ;

VEHICLEID
V00001
V00002
V00003
V00004
V00005
V00006
V00007
V00008
V00009
V00010
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=70f6853695b9f7a8c560d1fe26f06d52)

Comment: Notice that the sequence just keeps incrementing eg if you run the update again (don't do it!), you'd get higher numbers for the vehicleid. If this happens, and you want the original numbers 1 ... x again, just DROP the sequence, and run the update again.

Answer (score 0):

The identifier code of a table is recommended to be a numeric data, what you could do is an extra field that works as a second code, perhaps called secondary_code. You can do it with Stored Procedure, I give you a small example:

```
DELIMITER$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_genwrar_code$$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_genwrar_code(
OUT p_secondary_code VARCHAR(4) 
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE accountant INT;
    BEGIN
        SET accountant = (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM product); 
        IF(accountant <10)THEN
            SET p_secondary_code= CONCAT('V00',accountant );
            ELSE IF(accountant<100) THEN
                SET p_secondary_code= CONCAT('V0',accountant);
                ELSE IF(accountant<1000)THEN
                    SET p_secondary_code= CONCAT('V',accountant );
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF; 
    END;
END$$
```

With that you can generate codes as you need with the structure 'V001'

Comment: _"The identifier code of a table is recommended to be a numeric data"_  Perhaps in some people's standards.  Please cite your source.  Otherwise, that's just one person's opinion against another's.